# Stock Dividends & Splits: Are they always applied over night?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, dividends, historical-data, yahoo-finance

I'm using historical stock data, and I am wondering if I need to account for dividends, splits, and corporate actions **during** a trading day? I know that they often occur at the end of the day, and an adjusted close price would reflect that. Basically, can I interpret intraday data literally?

Second, is the market opening price always equal to the adjusted close of the previous trading day?

Third, Using Yahoo Finance APIs, I am able to obtain dividend and split info via http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/x?s=GOOG&g=v. Is there a way to tell whether a dividend was a stock dividend or a cash dividend?

Comment: Yes, you can "interpret intraday trading literally". The adjusted close is the previous day's close after adjustment for the corporate event (dividend, split).  It always occurs after the close and before trading resumes the next day.  The open the next day will be up, down or unchanged, depending on the market pressure when trading resumes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never seen a dividend, split or other corporate action during the day, but I have seen trade suspended a few times when something big happened.

The market opening price is not in general the same as the close of the previous day. It can gap up or down and does frequently.

I don't know of an api to find out if the dividend was cash or stock, but stock dividends are a lot less common.

Comment: There were 191 stock dividends in the same stock last in the last 12 months on US major-exchange-listed securities.  If you also consider spinoffs of other classes of securities which are a form of stock dividend (but treatment of them varies) there were 41 of those.